# Changing the Visibility of PanoramaItem using C# in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am enabling the visibility of a panoramaItem to visible using C#. As a default the panoramaItem is set to Collapsed. See below:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="select" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="SelectGroup">
            <TextBlock Text="HI" Margin="30" FontSize="36"></TextBlock>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Now there is a TextBlock and I have created a Tap event:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="SeachBloodGroup" Text="A+" FontSize="30" Tap="BloodGroup_Tap"></TextBlock>
```

Code:

```
private void BloodGroup_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    SelectGroup.Visibility = SelectGroup.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;           
}
```

But the panoramaItem is not showing.

Comment: does `BloodGroup_Tap` is executed?

Comment: Yes.. But still nothing is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void BloodGroup_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectGroup.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed)
        SelectGroup.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    else
        SelectGroup.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```